# Miller Columns Jumping (CSS/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, miller-columns

I found a JSfiddle that would help me immensely on a personal project. The columns jump (at the end of the example) instead of replacing each other because of a bit of CSS (ul.column.collapse). I'm struggling with this bug, any thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/yckart/cbtnemc7/

```
/* Setting a list container class to "collapsed" will hide the column. */
ul.column.collapse {
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
```